# WF4 - what is the right way of calling NativeActivityContext.ScheduleDelegate?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

```
public class NativeActivity1 : NativeActivity
{
    public NativeActivity1()
    {
        var myDynamicActivity = ActivityXamlServices.Load(@"C:\WorkflowConsoleApplication1\WorkflowConsoleApplication1\Workflow1.xaml") as DynamicActivity;
        var argInt32 = new InOutArgument<int>();

        this.ChildActivity = new DynamicActivity
        {
            Properties = { new DynamicActivityProperty() { Name="argInt32", Type=typeof(InOutArgument<int>), Value=argInt32 }, },
            Implementation = () => new Sequence
            {
                Activities =
                {
                    myDynamicActivity,
                    new WriteLine { Text = new InArgument<string>(ctx => argInt32.Get(ctx).ToString()) }
                }
            }
        };
    }
    public DynamicActivity ChildActivity { get; set; }
    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        var parameter = 10;
        while (0 < parameter--)
        {
            var activityInstance = context.ScheduleDelegate(
                new ActivityAction { Handler = this.ChildActivity }
                , new Dictionary<string, object> { { "argInt32", parameter } }
                , (activityContext, completedInstance, outArguments) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Output:" + outArguments["argInt32"].ToString());
                }, (faultContext, propagatedException, propagatedFrom) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Fault");
                });
        }
    }
}

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(new NativeActivity1());
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end the process ...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I have a while loop which makes the iteration from 1 to 10. every incremental number gets passed to the workflow and workflow supposes to return the negative value by multiplying with -1. since i have to stay in the Execute method and perform the iterations, I thought the only way to call workflow with parameters is using NativeActivityContext.ScheduleDelegate. The only limitation in the program is not to use WorkflowInvoker.Invoke. does somebody know how to use ScheduleDelegate?

Thanks, Moiz

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to do here. You are calling a DynamicActivity that has no arguments, just variables, with input arguments.

Comment: Maurice, I updated my question. please post if you know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a sample that might help you.  See [WF4 How To Invoke a Child Workflow as XAML](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/03/29/wf4-how-to-invoke-a-child-workflow-as-xaml.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Ron for your answer, I was looking for a way to do it in the code. I'm still wondering how to use NativeActivityContext.ScheduleDelegate. I have a scenario at my work where I do several things before calling the workflow to build the arguments. since i'm getting performance hit when i use Workflow.Invoker in the loop, i was interested to see if i can stay inside the runtime and make a call to ScheduleDelegate so that i don't need to invoke Invoker over n over.